# Tapku Library - Show Appointment Detail

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, tapku

I have a TKCalendarDayTimelineView displaying several events.  When I click on an event it fires the gotSingleTapAtPoint method.  Using this method, I want to display the details of the event that was clicked on in a new view.  How do I go about this?  Is there a way to determine what event was chosen from the selected point?

```
- (void)tapDetectingView:(TapDetectingView *)view gotSingleTapAtPoint:(CGPoint)tapPoint
{
    //get the selected event, use the details to init a new view
    CGPoint pointInTimeLine = CGPointZero;
    pointInTimeLine = [view convertPoint:tapPoint toView:self.scrollView];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the optional `calendarDayTimelineView:eventViewWasSelected` method of the `TKCalendarDayTimelineViewDelegate` protocol. Don't mess with `tapDetectingView:gotSingleTapAtPoint`.

```
- (void)calendarDayTimelineView:(TKCalendarDayTimelineView*)calendarDayTimeline eventViewWasSelected:(TKCalendarDayEventView *)eventView 
{
   // Access the event that was tapped by "eventView.sourceEvent". Something like:
   EKEvent *event = eventView.sourceEvent;
   // Now use EKEventViewController to display the event
}
```